# How to prevent duplicate code while doing microservice or soa ? or how to define the bounded context without duplicating the models?

Tags: soa, microservices

Can somebody please refer me how do we separate out the models while separating out each service to run of their own? So basically a few of the models we have right now overlaps among services. I went through some of the procedures which ask to use canonical pattern, however I also got that we should not use canonical pattern.

One of the solution would be to keep all the models in a common place which we are doing right now. But its seems problematic for managing the services in the form of one repository per one service.

Duplicate models are also fine with me if I can find good logic for it.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical slicing and domain decomposition leads to having each vertical slice have it's own well defined fields (not entities) that belong together (bounded context/business functions), defining a logical service boundary and decomposing the Service Boundary to Business Components and Autonomous Components (smallest unit of work).

Each component owns the data it modifies and is the only one in the system that can change the state of that data, you can have many copies of the data for readers but only one logical writer.

There for it makes more sense not to share these data models as they are internal to the component responsible for the data model's state (and is encapsulated).

Data readers can use view models and these are dictated more by the consumer then the producer, the view/read models hold the "real"/"current" state of the transactional data (which is private to the data modifier), read data can be updated by the data processor after any logical state change.

So it makes more sense to publish view/read models for read only consumers...

Check out [Udi Dahan's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTArpO7rSQE)

Does that make sense?